# W3C validator shows new error: "Meta requires 'name' attribute"

Tags: meta, w3c-validation, facebook-opengraph, rdfa

The w3C validator was all fine with this code:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="--Sitename--" />
```

If I replace the `property` attribute with `name`, the validator says `og:site_name` is not registered.

All of a sudden today it displayed this error:

> Error Line 7, Column 66: Element `meta` is missing required attribute `name`.

Nothing is changed but this error popped up.

Anyone knows why, and the solution for that?

Comment: what doctype do you use? html5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For HTML5

If a `meta` element has the `property` attribute (from RDFa), the `name` attribute is **not** required.

See the section "[Extensions to the HTML5 Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-html-rdfa-20150317/#extensions-to-the-html5-syntax)" from the W3C Recommendation *HTML+RDFa 1.1 - Second Edition*:

> If the RDFa `@property` attribute is present on the `meta` element, neither the `@name`, `@http-equiv`, nor `@charset` attributes are required and the `@content` attribute MUST be specified.

So your markup is fine:

```html
<meta property="og:site_name" content="--Sitename--" />
```

But it’s (now) even valid if you use the `name` attribute instead of RDFa’s `property`, because [the OGP values are registered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17724885/1591669). So this is fine, too:

```html
<meta name="og:site_name" content="--Sitename--" />
```

And you could even [combine both ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429551/1591669):

```html
<meta name="og:site_name" property="og:site_name" content="--Sitename--" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get what validator and in what mode you're using. Suppose it's [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org). Than notice that HTML5 support there is "experimental". And "property" tags refer to rdfa which is part of HTML5 [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-rdfa/). To dive in further details one need your code snippet or page url...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem which I find really borring.

This might not be the answer you were waiting for but I recommend using http://validator.nu/ instead of W3C validator.

Comment: Why on earth would you use a third party validator when you can use the one provided by W3C? -1

Comment: Mainly for two reasons: more up to date with HTML5 and because w3c validator is sometimes down. It is then always good to have a backup solution.