# Trying to validate HTML on Joomla 2.5 site but I have some meta-problems

Tags: html, validation, joomla, joomla2.5, meta-tags

I´m currently trying to clean up a Joomla 2.5 site for HTML validation but I have a problem.

The HTML validator is reporting the following errors:

> Bad value og:title for attribute name on element meta: Keyword og:title is not registered.

> Bad value og:type for attribute name on element meta: Keyword og:type is not registered

> Bad value og:url for attribute name on element meta: Keyword og:url is not registered

> Bad value og:site_name for attribute name on element meta: Keyword og:site_name is not registered

I have found out that the meta name attribute "og:xxxx" is generated only on pages that are linked to an article menu item. Unfortunately the front page is linked to such a menu item and I don´t know were the "og:" part is coming from.

I have tried to Google the problem and the only thing I can think is that it has do with Open Graph.

Comment: I would check the plugins that are turned on for your site. I'm not sure that this is default Joomla behavior

Comment: Yea, I have tried to locate any plugins or components that might cause this problem but I haven´t been able to find anything suspecious yet. I feel that I need to know what the "og:"-part of the name attribute means.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with it, but it looks to be primarily Facebook specific. If you have a Facebook plugin of some kind, that is probably what is inserting the tag. At this point though, you would have to balance HTML5 validation with having Facebook on the site. I would typically lean towards Facebook over being specifically valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`og:title`, `og:type`, `og:url` and `og:site_name` are values from the [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/).

If they are not hardcoded in your theme, they are probably coming from a plugin (look for "Facebook", "Share" or "SEO" plugins).

However: Using these `name` values is **not invalid**! They are registered at [MetaExtensions in the WHATWG wiki](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions), which makes them valid [according to the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#other-metadata-names). The validator is probably not up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had a feeling it had to do with Open Graph. Nice to know that I don´t need to change this anyways.